# Small sample-size, two sample test, power calculation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-power

We have two normally distributed random variables with means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$. We test the null hypothesis $H_0:\mu_X-\mu_Y=\delta=0$, at significance level $\alpha$ in a two-tailed test. We sample from both populations ($n_X,\sigma_X^2$,$n_Y,\sigma_Y^2$ may be taken as known). I want to calculate the power of the test as a function of the true difference in means $\delta$. However, the problem is that $n_X$ and $n_Y$ are small (in the region of 2-5 each) and so the Welch–Satterthwaite equation provides degrees of freedom between 1 and 2, which seem to provide invalid final results.

Is it acceptable, instead of using degrees of freedom, to circumvent the df for the t-test by converting to a normal distribution? Then the power could simply be

$$P \left( |Z|>\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-\delta}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_X^2}{n_X}+\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{n_Y}}} \right)$$

where $Z$ follows N(0,1). This is fine for a normal t-test, I believe, but in this case I am using the Welch t-test formula as the samples have unequal variances.

Is this correct? If not, how else should I calculate the power as a function of $\delta$?

Comment: If variances are known you do not need t-distribution.

Comment: To expand on @Vadim (+1), if you know the variances, you don't need Welch at all.  Or are you simply referring to the power calculation, not to the actual test?

Comment: I just want to carry out the calculation for power; not concerned about the result of the test.

Comment: Yes, but for the power calculation, if you don't know $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y$, it will make a real difference in the power, especially with those small samples.  Do you really want to ignore that?

Comment: Sorry, we do know the variances as well as number of sampled observations (as I specified, $n_X,\sigma_X^2$,$n_Y,\sigma_Y^2$ are all ‘known’, i.e. their values are given parameters). It remains the case we are comparing two populations of unequal variance for the difference in means, so I thought Welch t-test would be the best option; if not, how should I go about it correctly?

Comment: Just use the Normal distribution calculations as in the formula you've entered in the question.  t-tests are for when variances aren't known but need to be estimated from the sample, so you can avoid them in this case and go directly to the Normal distribution, which is exact.

Comment: Thanks so you’re saying my formula is correct for the power in this case. The only problem is I’ve only seen this transformation (to the normal distribution) applied for standard t-tests, not Welch cases. How can I prove that it applies also to Welch tests (where the two samples have unequal variance)?

Comment: I understand I may be thinking about it wrong from the start. In which case maybe you could explain how to solve / set up the solution from the start as you would do it. Of course once I get to the formula I wrote there are few issues, but to derive that convincingly for this problem is where I’m struggling.